# How to generate 10 character alphanumeric sequence strings in Python

Tags: python

I’ve been looking for an efficient Python code to generate 10 character alphanumeric strings. The string should start from “AA0AA0000A” and should increase the sequence from right to left

The code I've tried:

```
import string
from itertools import permutations as p

alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits

for a, b in p(alpha, 2):
    for c in p(num, 1):
        for d, e in p(alpha, 2):
            for f, g, h, i in p(num, 4):
                for j in p(alpha, 1):
                    print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

and the output sample I got:

```
A B ('0',) A B 0 1 2 3 ('A',)
A B ('0',) A B 0 1 2 3 ('B',)
A B ('0',) A B 0 1 2 3 ('C',)
```

But the output I expect is like

```
A A 0 A A 0 0 0 0 A
A A 0 A A 0 0 0 0 B
A A 0 A A 0 0 0 0 C
```

Is there a better or efficient way to generate the sequence of strings?

Comment: Is the question about why some of the elements are printed out in a tuple format and you wanted them to be strings or is the question about efficiency? If the former, then it is because permutations method returns a tuple https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations. If latter, then you need to define efficiency - are you after faster execution, big-O, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

# ...
for p in product(alpha, alpha, num, alpha, alpha, num, num, num, num, alpha):
    print(*p)
```

Note, however, that this loop will never end (or after 1188137600000 iterations if you have the time) =)
So you might want to go for a generator function to make handling easier:

```
def gen():
    for p in product(alpha, alpha, num, alpha, alpha, num, num, num, num, alpha):
        yield ''.join(p)

>>> g = gen()
>>> next(g)
'AA0AA0000A'
>>> next(g)
'AA0AA0000B'
>>> next(g)
'AA0AA0000C'
```